OpenAI Assistants API error: "'Assistants' has no attribute 'files'"
I have the code below, which I have to integrate, but it's showing up that 'Assistants' have no attribute 'file'. This code is around 8 months old, and I understand that the API probably changed since then, but I cannot find any alternatives to this in the documentation. Does anyone have any experience migrating this code?
assistant_file = client.beta.assistants.files.create(
    assistant_id = st.session_state.assistant_id,
    file_id = st.session_state.file_id,
)


The method you're trying to use (i.e., .files.create) doesn't exist.
Moreover, this code wouldn't work even with the OpenAI Assistants API v1.
If you want to create an assistant, use the following code (works with the OpenAI Assistants API v2):
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

my_assistant = client.beta.assistants.create(
    instructions="You are a personal math tutor. When asked a question, write and run Python code to answer the question.",
    name="Math Tutor",
    tools=[{"type": "code_interpreter"}],
    model="gpt-4o",
)

print(my_assistant)

If you want to create a file for an assistant, use the following code (works with the OpenAI Assistants API v2):
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

my_file = client.files.create(
  file=open("mydata.jsonl", "rb"),
  purpose="assistants"
)

print(my_file)

